# add checkbox on input type number change

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to know how to add checkboxes on input type number change.

By default I have :

**HTML CODE**

```
<label for checkbox_number>Number of checkboxes :</label>
<input id="checkbox_number" name="checkbox_number" type="number" size="1" maxlength="1" value="1" onkeydown="change_cb()"/>

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="cb1">
```

If I change my *checkbox number* to 2, I would like javascript/ajax add

```
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="cb2">
```

Same as if I change my *change number* to 1, it has to remove one checkbox.

I already did same thing but with table (add one row or remove one row) but here i don't know how to add new element (on my first script I don't add new table, just new row)...

Need help to write my JS function **change_cb()**

---

**EDIT TO GIVE YOU MY ANSWER**

I find how to do this with DADE help (thank you DADE) :

**HTML CODE (same)**

```
<label for="cb_number">How many checkboxes ?</label>
<input id="cb_number" name="cb_number" type="number" size="1" maxlength="1" value="1">
<div class="my_cb_result"></div>
```

**jQuery CODE**

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('#cb_number').on('keyup mouseup', function() {
        var number = parseInt($(this).val());
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').remove();
        $('label[class="to_del"]').remove();
        for (var i=1;i<=number;i++) {
            var data = '<label for="checkbox" class="to_del">Label of my checkbox</label><input id="checkbox'+i+'" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'+i+'">';
        }
        $('.my_cb_result').append(data);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle with comments](http://jsfiddle.net/2CtNv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<label for checkbox_number>Number of checkboxes :</label>
<input id="checkbox_number" name="checkbox_number" type="number" size="1" maxlength="1" value="0">
<div class="inputs"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#checkbox_number').on('keyup mouseup', function() {
    var number = parseInt($(this).val());
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').remove();
    for (var i=1;i<=number;i++) {
        var data = '<input id="checkbox'+i+'" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="cb'+i+'">';
        $('.inputs').append(data);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle with comments](http://jsfiddle.net/c5ZWL/3/)

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought you'll need jQuery script, my bad. Maybe you'll understand logic or someone will write it in pure JS or I'll write it when I'll get home. :)

Comment: don't worry, i'll use jQuery, when i said JS i meant javascript/AJAX/jQuery, or other dynamix language :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var ele = '<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="cb2">';
document.getElementById("yourElementID").appendChild(ele);
```

Comment: Your answer works, look at my edit to look what did i expect. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean if `checkbox_number`'s value is set to "`2`" that you'd like to render the second checkbox?

If so, you should use `onblur` or similar on `checkbox_number` to run a function that will render the new one via a `getElementById` and `appendChild`.

IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_cb() {
var secondCheckbox = '<input id="checkbox_number2" name="checkbox_number" type="number" size="1" maxlength="1" value="1" />";
document.getElementById("yourForm").appendChild(secondCheckBox);
}
</script>

<div id="yourForm">

<label for checkbox_number>Number of checkboxes :</label>
<input id="checkbox_number" name="checkbox_number" type="number" size="1" maxlength="1" value="1" onblur="change_cb()"/>

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="cb1">

</div>
```

edit: From what you're posting, you shouldn't need Ajax, by the way.

Comment: Your answer works too, and DADE answer help me to add more than 1 checkbox. Look at my edit to look at what did i expect. Thank you by the way.

Comment: No problem! If you wouldn't mind upvoting both of our answers it'd be appreciated. :)